# Issue with multiple subquery structure

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use multiple subqueries below so that I can use (and eventually sum) my case statement aliases. The query runs fine but it's returning provgrpcodes that are not limited to 'MIM' and 'XIMD' for instance. Basically I want to treat each subquery as a table or dataset as it should be.

```
SELECT t.px
 , t.provgrpcode
 , t.revctrdesc
 , t.pgrp_prov_combo
 , sum(t.CorrectedUnits) as measure

 from 
 (SELECT q.px
 , q.provgrpcode
 , q.revctrdesc
 , q.pgrp_prov_combo
 , q.postingdate
 , q.correcteddate
 , q.corrected
 , case when q.corrected = 'Y' and q.correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And    '2015-02-01' and q.postingdate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01' and        q.txtype = 'c' then 0
   when q.corrected = 'y' and q.correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And    '2015-02-01' and q.postingdate Not Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01' and    q.txtype = 'c' then - q.rvuunitadjustment
   when q.txtype = 'c' then q.rvuunitadjustment
   else 0 end as CorrectedUnits
 from 
 (SELECT db1.px
 , db1.provgrpcode
 , db2.revctrdesc
 , prov.pgrp_prov_combo
 , db1.postingdate
 , db1.correcteddate
 , db1.corrected
 , db1.txtype
 , case when db1.procmod2='tc' then 0
   when db1.procmod1='tc' then 0
   when substring(db1.proccode,6,2)='tc' then 0
   else db1.totalunits
   end as RVUUnitAdjustment
 FROM Damariscotta..Damariscotta_Monthly_Data as db1 
 LEFT JOIN pp_reporting..RevenueCenter_union_v as db2 ON db1.px = db2.px 
 AND db1.revctrcode = db2.revctrcode
 LEFT JOIN pp_reporting..Providers prov ON db1.provcode = prov.pgrp_prov_cd 
 AND db1.px = prov.pgrp_practice
 )q
 )t
 WHERE px ='dmm' 
 AND postingdate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01' OR px='dmm' AND                correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01'
 --adding these for other queries
 AND revctrdesc like '%exam%'
 and provgrpcode in ('MIM','XIMD')
 group by px, provgrpcode, revctrdesc, revctrdesc, pgrp_prov_combo
```

Thank you - this worked

```
  WHERE
  (db1.px ='dmm' 
  AND postingdate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01') OR (db1.px='dmm'      AND correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01')
  )q
  )t
  WHERE 
  --px ='dmm' 
  --AND postingdate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01' OR px='dmm' AND    correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01'
  --adding these for other queries
  revctrdesc like '%exam%'
  and provgrpcode in ('MIM','XIMD')
  group by px, provgrpcode, revctrdesc, revctrdesc, pgrp_prov_combo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things.

First, put your where clause in the inner most subquery you can. That will increase your query's efficiency.

Second AND has priority over or, so this:

```
WHERE px ='dmm' 
AND postingdate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01' OR px='dmm' AND                   correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01'
--adding these for other queries
AND revctrdesc like '%exam%'
and provgrpcode in ('MIM','XIMD')
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
WHERE (px ='dmm' 
AND postingdate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01') OR (px='dmm' AND                   correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01'
--adding these for other queries
AND revctrdesc like '%exam%'
and provgrpcode in ('MIM','XIMD'))
```

Which means that if

```
px ='dmm' 
AND postingdate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01'
```

is true, then the record will be returned even if

px='dmm' AND                   correcteddate Between '2015-01-01' And '2015-02-01'
    --adding these for other queries
    AND revctrdesc like '%exam%'
    and provgrpcode in ('MIM','XIMD')

is false.

Comment: thank you for your response. The only place I can put the criteria is within the last subquery (q) is this what you mean by most inner? I think I need to re evaluate the OR statements. (I'm rewriting this from an awful acccess query built in design mode).

Comment: Thank you. I had to seperate the or from the rest of the criteria.